# Search for a phrase in a cell and return by the hierarchically highest value google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with columns with values like this:

[image: coluns]

I want to use a script to search for words according to this hierarchy:

CHECK
ACTIVE
NEGOTIATED
SUSPENDED REQUIREMENT
EXTINGUISHED

The script must look for the words inside the cell and if it finds the word CONFERIR, it will replace the content with CONFERIR, if it does not find CONFERIR but finds ATIVA it replaces it with ATIVA, if it does not find CONFERIR nor ATIVA, but it finds NEGOCIADA it replaces the cell content for NEGOCIADA, if you do not find CONFEFER, ATIVA or NEGOCIADA, but find EXIGIBILIDADE SUSPENSA, substitute the content for EXIGIBILIDADE SUSPENSA,
if you do not find CONFERIR, ATIVA, NEGOCIADA, EXIGIBILIDADE SUSPENSA but find EXTINTA, replace it with EXTINTA. if none of the situations are found, replace VERIFY
example (In the first column the result must be replaced by the second):

[image: replaced]

My code:

```
function applyHierarchy() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var columnFRange = sheet.getRange("F2:F" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = columnFRange.getValues();

  var hierarchy = ["CONFERIR", "ATIVA", "EXIGIBILIDADE SUSPENSA", "NEGOCIADA", "EXTINTA", "VERIFICAR"];

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (typeof values[i][0] === 'string') {
      var lines = values[i][0].split(';\n');
      var overallSituation = hierarchy.length - 1; // começa com o menor situação prioritária
      for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
        // Atualiza a situação geral se for superior na hierarquia
        var situationIndex = hierarchy.indexOf(lines[j].trim());
        if (situationIndex !== -1 && situationIndex < overallSituation) {
          overallSituation = situationIndex;
        }
      }
      // Define o valor da célula para a situação geral
      values[i][0] = hierarchy[overallSituation];
    }
  }

  sheet.getRange("F2:F" + sheet.getLastRow()).setValues(values);
}
```

It happens that when you find:
"EXIBILIDADE SUSPENSA;
EXTINTA"

in the same cell it is returning EXTINTA, it should be EXIGIBILIDADE SUSPENSA

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `if none of the situations are found, replace VERIFY example (In the first column the result must be replaced by the second):` and `It happens that when you find: "EXIBILIDADE SUSPENSA; EXTINTA" in the same cell it is returning EXTINTA, it should be EXIGIBILIDADE SUSPENSA`. Can I ask you about the detailed logic for your expected result? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Search Phrases on Cell that will return value based on Hierarchy:

So what I have created is a script that will run through F col, and find the highest hierarchy based on your explanation.

### Sample Code:

```
function applyHierarchy() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var columnFRange = sheet.getRange("F1:F" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = columnFRange.getValues(); ""
  var hierarchy = ["CONFERIR", "ATIVA", "EXIGIBILIDADE SUSPENSA", "NEGOCIADA", "EXTINTA", "VERIFICAR"];
  var updatedData = [];

  loop1:
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var currentString = values[i][0].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").split(";");
    loop2:
    for (j = 0; j < hierarchy.length; j++) {
      // console.log(hierarchy[j] + "" + [j])
      if (currentString.includes(hierarchy[j])) {
        updatedData.push([hierarchy[j]])
        break;
      }
      else if (!currentString.some(r=>hierarchy.includes(r))){
        updatedData.push(["Verify"])
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  columnFRange.setValues(updatedData);
}
```

### Reference:

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[Includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)